# How to get zoom level from latlongBounds in android

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, latitude-longitude

I am new to android. I have used latlongbound in my app. But i want to store this zoomlevel so that user will see again the same zoom level. I have seen many question about it. But didnt got the answer. Can anyone please help me out on this.

below is my code how i am using latlongbounds

```
 public void zoomCameraBasedOnNumberOfMarkes(Marker[] markers) {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
        builder.include(new LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude));
        LatLngBounds markerBound = builder.build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(markerBound, 50));
    }
```

Comment: why do you want zoom level for?

Comment: you can add animation listener for map, and when animation will be finished - just ask map of zoom level )